# Invalid input syntax using jsonb_to_recordset inside a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function that iterates a jsonb array but I'm facing a weird error message that totally blocked me. This is my test case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
    FUNCTION public.questiontemplate_match_customattributes(
        id int,
        customattributes jsonb
) 
RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$function$
DECLARE
    group_attrs JSONB;
    attr JSONB;
    attr_name TEXT;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Test 1';
    FOR attr IN (select * from jsonb_to_recordset(customattributes) AS x("name" TEXT, "value" TEXT)) LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Test 2';
    END LOOP;
    RETURN FALSE;
END $function$;


SELECT
    questiontemplate_match_customattributes(
        12,
        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object('name', 'pack', 'value', 'box'),
            jsonb_build_object('name', 'brand', 'value', 'pepsi')
        )
    )
```

When I run the queries above I get the following message

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
> Detail: Token "pack" is invalid.
> Where: JSON data, line 1: pack
> PL/pgSQL function questiontemplate_match_customattributes(integer,jsonb) line 8 at FOR over SELECT rows

and only `Test 1` appear in my output but when I run

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_to_recordset(
    jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object('name', 'pack', 'value', 'box'),
            jsonb_build_object('name', 'brand', 'value', 'pepsi')
    )
) AS x("name" TEXT, "value" TEXT)
```

I get the right recordset. Any advice?

Version: Postgres 12.5

Enviroment: Docker

Comment: Variable `attr JSONB` should become `attr record` and it works.

Comment: that's it! I totally missed the type.

Comment: Pls. see an addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the type of variable `attr` from `JSONB` to `record` or - if you need it as JSONB - change the loop query to produce JSONB as below.

```sql
FOR attr IN select to_jsonb(x) from jsonb_to_recordset(customattributes) AS x("name" TEXT, "value" TEXT) LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%', attr;
END LOOP;
```

BTW the loop query may be simplified as

```sql
FOR attr IN select jsonb_array_elements(customattributes) LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%', attr;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: I tried in this way before (that is why the attr was JSONB) but then I face another issue when I try to use `attr->'name'` to check if the key is present in another JSON. Something like

`group_attrs := '{"pack": ["box"], "brand": ["coca", "pepsi"]}';`
`group_attrs ? attr->'name'`

Comment: This is because `attr->'name'` returns JSONB. To extract the value as text use `attr->>'name'`. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING).